# How to find screenspace position of eye gaze with Hololens 2 in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I want to create an application for a hololens 2 where I access the primary video feed from the hololens camera and then use the eye gaze feature to see where the user is looking. Is there a way I can create a single video that has an overlay signifying where the user is looking? Any help is greatly appriciated :)

I already know how to access the main camera from the hololens, but I don't know how I can overlay a point signifying where the user is looking.

Comment: Have you tried setting the GazeCursor to be visible? You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/input/eye-tracking/eye-tracking-eye-gaze-provider?view=mrtkunity-2022-05 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.input.imixedrealitycursor?view=mixed-reality-toolkit-unity-2020-dotnet-2.8.0.